# Installing Multiple Linux Distros in a single partition

Tags: partition, distributions

I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04, elementaryos, and Windows 8. I would also like to install Backtrack for rare use. But I'm already out of my partition limit. So is it possible to combine two partitions and install all the Linux distros in that single partition with a shared swap?

Answer (score 2):

For this, [lubi](http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lubi.html) is your friend.

EDIT:

Lubi is used to install any other Linux OS in the same partition as that of Linux.
It means, if you are out of partition or you do not want to create an extra partition for any reason, then you can install the Linux onto same partition.

I have used similar technology for dual booting into same partition. I used the wubi. It's almost same, only difference is that, base OS is Window.

I had installed my own custom OS using WUBI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Link is provided for the same reason...  :)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged due to various reasons (linkrot, also the fact that your "answer" is not an answer). Please include the context in your answer.